# Python - why I must use self in this method?

Tags: python

```
class ValidateStrategy(abc.ABC):
    def validate(self, input_string):
        pass


class IntValidateStrategy(ValidateStrategy):
    def validate(self, input_string):
        try:
            int(input_string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False


def string_validate(input_string, validate_strategy):
    return validate_strategy.validate(input_string)

string_validate("22", IntValidateStrategy)
```

Why am I getting an error because the self argument is missing?

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\Pobrane\drive\test.py",
> line 11, in <module>
>     print(el + ": " + str(validator.string_validate(el, validator.IntValidateStrategy)))   File
> "F:\Pobrane\drive\validator.py", line 34, in string_validate
>     return validate_strategy.validate(input_string) TypeError: IntValidateStrategy.validate() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'input_string'
```

Comment: You passed in the class itself into validator.string_validate(), did you meen to instead pass in an instance of IntValidateStrategy? e.g. `validator.string_validate("22", validator,IntValidateStrategy())`? Either that or you can make the validate function into a static function, allowing you to call it on the class without passing in a "self" isntance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, you don't need to.

Whenever you call a method of a class, unless it is decorated as a `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` the first argument will be the instance of the class the method was called from.

To explain:

If I call the method `x` as `Class.x()`, then no first argument will be automatically passed.

If I call the method `x` as `instance.x()` the first argument will be the instance.

You are passing `IntValidateStrategy` to your function. This means that the first argument in the function will be the class `IntValidateStrategy`.

Since you aren't accessing any variables within the class, you can add the decorator `@staticmethod` above your method definition, and remove the `self` argument since nothing is being passed automatically.

This means when you call `IntValidateStrategy.validate(...)`, nothing is passed automatically and you are free to use your function.

Code:

```py
class IntValidateStrategy(ValidateStrategy):
    @staticmethod
    def validate(input_string):
        try:
            int(input_string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Comment: One key clarification for second point: the first argument will _implicitly_ be the instance (`instance`). This trips a lot of people up!

Comment: But why when I don't use them as static do I have such an error? In my opinion, it should not be present. In theory, I know I can convert it to static, but I'm interested in this particular case without staticmethod. The advice about staticmethod is correct, but I am well aware of this solution. I just want to know what happened here that makes the compiler react to the given code.

Comment: When you don't have them as static, they are automatically expecting the first argument to be an instance the instance or class the method was called from.
I would reccomend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXApHXsDe8I&t=48s) on static, class and instance methods

Comment: I know how self works, but I haven't noticed one detail. When we pass a function, it's without the parentheses. But I don't pass a function there, it's just an object instance constructor. In a word, it was a Czech mistake, probably caused by fatigue. Generally, your comments were valuable, but it was about something completely different, I just got it wrong. I gave the validate_strategy argument as: IntValidateStrategy instead of DateValidateStrategy ()!

Answer (score 2):

Functions are non-data descriptors in Python.

When you access a function through a class, you get the function exactly as you defined it. As a concrete example, `IntValidateStrategy.validate` is a function that accepts two named positional arguments, `self`, and `string`.

Descriptor magic is invoked when you access a function through an instance of a class. Descriptor protocol means calling `validate.__get__(instance)`. For regular functions, this returns a *bound method* object, which has a parameter list that does not explicitly include the first positional parameter of the function you defined, `self`. A concrete example would be if you instantiated your strategy:

```
IntValidateStrategy().validate('234')
```

The simplest fix for your example would be to instantiate the class you are passing in:

```
string_validate("22", IntValidateStrategy())
```

A better solution might be too allow `string_validate` to accept any callable as a validator:

```
def string_validate(input_string, validate_strategy):
    return validate_strategy(input_string)

string_validate("22", IntValidateStrategy().validate)
```

At this point, you don't need to even have `string_validate`. In fact you can simplify your interface and make it more flexible by replacing the name `validate` with `__call__`. You'll be able to use functions for stateless validators, and full classes if you need state:

```
class ValidateStrategy(abc.ABC):
    def __call__(self, input_string):
        pass

def stateless_int_validate_strategy(input_sting):
    try:
        int(input_string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

class StatefulIntValidateStrategy(ValidateStrategy):
    def __call__(self, input_string):
        return stateless_int_validate_strategy(input_sting)

stateless_int_validate_strategy("22")
validator = StatefulIntValidateStrategy()
validator("23")
```